# android change language listener

Tags: android, localization

Language can be changed in

Home > Menu > Settings > Locale & text > Select locale

I am wondering how can I detect such change? My application is seems to be turned off by system during such operation, however I have to be 100% sure, that this is official rule.

Do you know something about this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config says:

> android:configChanges
>   Lists configuration changes that the activity will handle itself. When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted. Instead, the activity remains running and its onConfigurationChanged() method is called.
>
> Note: Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last-resort. Please read Handling Runtime Changes for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change.
>
> Any or all of the following strings are valid values for this attribute. Multiple values are separated by '|' — for example, "**locale**|navigation|orientation".

Comment: I havent set the locale of my application in android:configChanges but the app crashes when changed the locale of phone.

Answer (score 20):

An Intent is broadcast for this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED

You can register a BroadcastReceiver in your manifest to handle it.

Comment: Fyi this is a safe broadcast even after SDK 26, since it is on the whitelist https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background-broadcasts.html