# Stop webview from reloading when user changes language?

Tags: android, webview, google-tv

I am building a GoogleTV app that contains a WebView. If I change the device's language while the app is loaded, then the webView refreshes. This is a very jarring experience and totally  unnecessary since my app only displays English.

How can I stop the webview from reloading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain, but guessing this is because your app is getting a [configuration change](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) restart due to a changing locale.

Try [suppressing this configuration change](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) by adding `android:configChanges="locale"` to the `<activity>` and see if it helps.

Comment: that fixed it! THANKS! I also found the following stackoverflow post that is related to this issue. The answer in that posts details other things that could be suppressed so the app doesn't reload.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741944/android-change-language-listener

Comment: Does not work here using a cordova (3.5.0-0.2.6) webview on a Nexus 7, running 4.4.4. :( Any other ideas?